# Typescript: define a type that can't hold anything

Tags: typescript

I'm interested (for the purpose of validation) in such a type, that variables of this type cannot have any value assigned to them. There is type `void`, but value of this type can contain the value `undefined`, so it's not exactly what I'm asking about.

It seems that I'm able to reproduce this behaviour used the intersection of incompatible types:

```
type nothing = true & false;
const nothingTrue: nothing = true; // error, true not assignable to false
const nothingFalse: nothing = false; // error, false not assignable to true
const nothingUndefined: nothing = undefined; // error, undefined not assignable to true
```

But this looks more like a hack. Maybe there is something more clear? Or is this the right way?

Comment: how about `never` ?

Comment: Just tested - that's it, thanks. Used this type before, but messed up with understanding. Sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you are looking for is the `never` type. From the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html):

> The never type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type; however, no type is a subtype of, or assignable to, never (except never itself). Even any isn’t assignable to never.